# Java regex.pattern matcher not returning desired results

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

The Java regex pattern matching does not appear to be returning the desired results even though other tools appear to match the desired pattern.  If the regex syntax is correct then is it something about the implementation of Java regex that I am not understanding?

Assume an argument string:

```
argList = -fbin -o program.asm -l listfile.lst
```

Here is my implementation

```
 String argPattern = "/(-o\\s*\\S+)|(-f\\s*\\S+)|(-l\\s*\\S+)/g";
 Pattern r = Pattern.compile(argPattern);
 Matcher m = r.matcher(argList);
 if (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
 }
```

The output of this routine just returns

```
-fbin, null, fbin
```

which makes no sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the delimiters and global modifier from your regular expression, Java does not use this syntax. Also, instead of three group constructs, I would utilize a character set.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-[ofl]\\s*\\S+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(argList);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the forwards slashes and `g` modifier , java and js uses two different methods for passing regex argument. And also note that `group(0)` prints the whole match where `group(x)` prints their corresponding matches.

```
 String argPattern = "(-o\\s*\\S+)|(-f\\s*\\S+)|(-l\\s*\\S+)";
```

Example:

```
String argPattern = "/(-o\\s*\\S+)|(-f\\s*\\S+)|(-l\\s*\\S+)/g";
 Pattern r = Pattern.compile(argPattern);
 Matcher m = r.matcher(argList);
 while (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3) );
 }
```

Comment: use `while` instead of if